# Bold tag in peer text widgets with different font size

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

In Tk, it's possible to create a peer of a text widget that displays the same
content. It's also possible to set the font of the peer to something different
than the font size of the original peer.

This works great until I want to make part of the text bold (in the original
widget, but it doesn't matter whether the peer text gets bolded too). As far as
I can tell by looking at [text(3tk)](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm),
there's no way to bold a part of the text other than creating a tag with a bold
font. But that font is then used in the peer as well, including the size of the
font.

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

text = tkinter.Text(root)
text.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
text.insert('end', 'hello world\n' * 10)

# Problem: the font size of the tag applies in both text widgets
text.tag_config('foo', font=('Monospace', 12, 'bold'))      
text.tag_add('foo', '2.2', '2.7')

peer = tkinter.Text(root)
peer.destroy()      # the underlying tk widget gets replaced with the peer
text.peer_create(peer, font=('Monospace', 3, ''))
peer.pack(side='left', fill='y')

root.mainloop()
```

How can I bold parts of the text while displaying the bolded text with
different sizes in the two text widgets?
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There is one tag that only applies to one of the peers. It's `sel`, and 
it represents the text being selected. This works:

```
peer.tag_config('sel', font=('Monospace', 3, ''))
peer.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')
```

A big downside is that the font size jumps back to the usual when the 
bolded part is unselected. If you don't need selecting for anything 
else, you can force all of the text to be always selected.